# Atomic RMW operations on a file

Tags: c++, file, concurrency, atomic

Is there a way I can issue an atomic RMW write to the entire contents of a file or a subset of the contents of a file with the write() APIs? With support for both failure-atomicity (i.e. the visible side-effects of the file write remain true even through process restarts) and concurrency-atomicity (i.e. for writes write(A), and write(B) the only possible values for the file after the writes finish are A or B)?

I was looking for something like a compare-exchange or a lower-level store-conditional sort of write.

Thanks!

Comment: There's certainly nothing of the kind in standard C or C++; it'd be OS specific.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't mean to ask for a std-specified way of doing this, but something in the family of write() functions or some external higher-level abstraction in the open-source community for C++.

Comment: This is more usually done with OS-provided file locking features; you take a write lock while modifying the file, and require all potential users to take a read lock to access it.  Unix also has atomic `rename(2)`, and I think I've heard that a single `write(2)` call may be atomic under certain conditions, but don't quote me on that.